# Asymptotic formula, polynomial, irrational number and uniformly distribution

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

> **Problem 1**
>   Given a irrational number $\alpha$ and two polynomials with positive integer coefficients $P(n),Q(n)$, is it possible to get the asymptotic estimate and reasonable error term for:
>   $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\#\{1\leq n\leq N \ | \ \exists m\in \mathbb N,  [P(n)\alpha]=Q(m)\}?$$

In the case when $Q(n)=an+b$, by Weyl method or van der curput trick it is not difficult to establish such a estimate at least for the asymptotic part, and if we know $\alpha$ is a smooth irrational number, we could even say some thing about the error term. In fact for smooth irrational number we have the following "effective uniformly distribution result".

> **Theorem (effective uniformly distribution)**
>   $\alpha \in \mathbb R- \mathbb Q$ is a smooth irrational number, then we have, $\forall 0<a<b<1$,
>   $$\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\ \{\alpha P(n)\}\in (a,b) \}=(b-a)N+O(log^{deg(P)}(N))$$

The proof of this theorem is based on a careful look at the continual fraction expansion of $\alpha$.

In the case $P(n)=n$ and $Q(n) $ is a arbitrarily monic integer polynomial (the highest order coefficient is 1) and $\alpha$ is smooth this problem is also not very difficult, we could establish the following asymptotic expansion,

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\ \exists m\in \mathbb N^*,\{n\alpha \}=Q(m) \}=N^{\frac{1}{deg(Q)}}$$

Although it seems not very easy to get a reasonable order of error term.

Although the general situation may be complicated, the typical situation I wondering to understand is the case $Q(n)=n^k+1$, and $P(n)$ is a arbitrary polynomial with positive integer coeficients, I conjecture the following asymptotic is true.

> **Problem 2**
>   $\alpha$ is a irrational number, $P(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficient, could the following asymptotic formula be true?
>   $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\ \exists m\in \mathbb N,[P(n)\alpha ]=m^k+1 \}}{N^{\frac{1}{k}}}=1$$

I will appreciate for any valuable comments and advice.

Comment: I don't know what ${\bf N}^*$ is. Also, in Problem 1, presumably you want $Q$ to have integer coefficients?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, corrected, for $\mathbb N^*$ I mean integer number and I assume both $Q(n),P(n)$ have integer coefficients.

Comment: I've seen $\bf N$ used for the natural numbers, and $\bf Z$ for the integers, but what's the rationale beind using ${\bf N}^*$ for the integers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, this is an embarrassed mistake... I always use this notation... created, thanks!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson In French at least $\mathbb{N}^*$ often denotes the nonzero natural numbers.

Comment: @François, OK, but then OP writes, "for ${\bf N}^*$ I mean integer number," so it looks like $\bf Z$ is meant. But then when OP edited, ${\bf N}^*$ became $\bf N$, so what's really meant is anybody's guess.

Comment: In Problem 2 you're taking the limit as $N\to\infty$ on the left hand side, so it's strange to also have $N$ on the right. Perhaps you want to divide by $N^{1/k}$ on the left instead?

Comment: @JoelMoreira, yes you are right! I have corrected.